# adding and quering the database in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql

I have added my database as a data source to my C# project in visual studio. Now, I would like to query the database. Do I need to manually set up a connection string with the database?

```
public void setSQL()
{
    string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\jasper\\Desktop\\AutoReg\\AutoReg.accdb;";

    OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
    MyConn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //query to ask
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Student";

    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            MyConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to go through all of this process every time when I need to query a database?

Comment: Consider using an ORM, or a basic LINQ-To-SQL model. Google around for information if you don't fancy writing SQL all of the time.

Comment: I just need to develop one pretty complicated query and I should be done...

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if you have to correct connection string, or just if there's a simpler way to go about this?

Comment: I agree with @KingCronus. Use a heavyweight ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework, or used a lightweight ORM like PetaPoco. Note this post from Jimmy Bogard: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/24/dont-write-your-own-orm/

Comment: ORM not always is a best idea!

Comment: valverij, Is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: To get data from SQL you need some basic things (that you already have) - connection string, connection object and command object. You look like you are doing the right stuff in your code - don't bother with an ORM if you don't need it - it will just add a lot of complexity to your project if it is very simple. Have you debugged to check that the dataset actually contains some data?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just manually setting up a db connection for literally just one query, there isn't really an easier way to do it. I would suggest that the code be cleaned up a little, though. As it is written in your example, `MyConn` will remain open if there is an error during your query. That can be fixed by switching it up and putting it in a `using`:

```
public void setSQL()
{
    string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jasper\Desktop\AutoReg\AutoReg.accdb;";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //query to ask
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Student";

    using (OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        MyConn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);                           
            }
        }
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; 
}
```

If you wanted to switch this up and make it easier for you if you need to add more queries in the future, though, then I'd suggest moving to a **3-tier architecture** with a Business Logic Layer (BLL) and a Data Access Layer (DAL). In this, you could have a base DAL class that defines some standard methods for things like `Fill()`,  `ExecuteScalar()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()`, etc.

You can find countless examples of this kind of set up across the internet, but I've put together a fairly simple example:

Here's a rough sketch of a possible DAL base class. Notice how it manages the actual connections to the database based on a DB command that is passed in:

```
public abstract class DALBase
{
    private const string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jasper\Desktop\AutoReg\AutoReg.accdb;";

    protected DataSet Fill(OleDbCommand command)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            command.Connection = myConn;
            myConn.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {                                    
                adapter.Fill(ds);                                    
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }

    protected void ExecuteNonQuery(OleDbCommand command)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            command.Connection =  myConn;                            
            myConn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    // put any other methods you need here    

}
```

And then you can make a table-specific DAL class for your Student table to handle the queries and commands. This keeps your query logic all in one place:

```
public class StudentDAL : DALBase
{
    public DataSet GetAllStudents()
    {
        DataSet ds = null;

        //query to ask
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Student";

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query))
        {
            ds = Fill(command);            
        }   

        return ds;     
    }

    public void UpdateStudentName(int studentID, string name)
    {            
        string query = "UPDATE Student SET Name = @Name WHERE StudentID = @StudentID";

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentID);

            ExecuteNonQuery(command);            
        }        
    }
}
```

Then, you would make a table-specific BLL class to handle any intermediary logic that needs to happen between the DAL and the class that needs the information from your database:

```
public class StudentBLL
{
    private _studentDAL = new StudentDAL();

    public DataSet GetAllStudents()
    {        
        return _studentDAL.GetAllStudents();                    
    }

    public void UpdateStudentName(Student student)
    {        
        _studentDAL.UpdateStudentName(student.StudentID, student.Name);                    
    }
}
```

In this particular case, the methods pretty much just make calls to the corresponding DAL. If you needed to do any other logic, though (type conversion, some kind of formula, etc.), this is where it would happen. I guess my hypothetical `UpdateStudentName` method, is a minor example of this. If you look at it, you'll see that it just takes in a `Student` object and splits it out to send to the DAL. This prevents the UI layer (or other calling class) from needing to worry about this.

Finally, you would make a call to your database *through* a BLL object from the class that needs the information:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    DataGridView dataGridView1;        

    public void PopulateDataGridView1()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new StudentBLL().GetAllStudents();
    }        
}
```

Now, this may not fit exactly into your needs, and I'm sure people could argue about this sort of approach, but this is meant to be more of an example of how you could go about streamlining your data access to make it far more maintainable and scalable down the road.